# What part of the ASP.NET Web API framework translates a user-defined object to a HttpResponseMessage?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

If you have a action in an ApiController like so:

```
public Foo GetFoo(int id)
{
  // ...
}
```

And from another .NET application of any type, you call this API end-point like so:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("http://localhost/api/foo/1", value);

    // ...
}
```

Then, the `HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync` method returns a `Task<HttpResponseMessage>` even when the API action returned a user-defined object of class `Foo`.

What part of the Web API does this translation? Does the client code always receive a `HttpResponseMessage`?

Answer (score 1):

HttpClient doesn't know that the response maps to the foo class. It simply returns the HTTP response encapsulated as a HttpResponseMessage.

If you want to map the response to a Foo object you must tell it to do so.

Example:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("http://localhost/api/foo/1", value);
    var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(); // Read the request body into a stream.
    // Map the body to a object of type Foo
    var foo = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter().ReadFromStream(typeof(Foo), stream, Encoding.UTF8, null);

    // Do whatever you want with foo...

}
```

Comment: I want to add to this now that a better way to do this would be to do straight var stream = await response.content.ReadAsync<Foo>();